# Read file on a Windows host in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Similar to the `Get-Content` command in PowerShell, I am looking for a way to read a file on a Windows target and save the file contents to a variable in Ansible. The documentation says that the `ansible.builtin.file` module is able to get file contents but this feature does not seem to be available for the `win_file` module.

The following pseudo-code should better explain what I'm trying to do:

```
- name: save file contents to variable
  win_get_content:
    path: C:\somefile.txt
  register: file_contents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if *"{{lookup('file', 'C:\somefile.txt') }}"* is not functional in window, you could try:

```
 - name: get content of file
   win_shell: 'type C:\somefile.txt'  
   register: file_contents

 - name: display content
   debug:  
     msg: "{{ file_contents.stdout_lines }} "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the module slurp.
It works on both windows and linux.

```
  - name: Read file
    ansible.builtin.slurp:
      src: '<path/to/file>'
    register: file

  - name: Print file content
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ file['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to read the file, it worked for me

```
- name: get some file  
  win_shell: get-content C:\somefile.txt   
  register: file-data 

- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{file-data}}"
```